# Much more Noise in the whole scene with a Light Points?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, noise-reduction

i am currently working on a steampunk castle and have the problem that the entire picture becomes significantly noisier as soon as I put normal points of light in the lamps. I set the light points to 100W to only illuminate the immediate area. But still everything seems to be affected by it in terms of the noise? How can that be?

Without Light Points:
[image]

With Light Points:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Small point lights can add noise, because of internal calculations:

[image]

I suggest disabling Multiple Importance for all unimportant lights, this should help, but I'm not sure, give a try. Also try set radius of lamp as big as it posible.

[image]

More info:

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies

Comment: I needed this answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've tried everything, but unfortunately no real improvement. The more illuminants I have, the noisier the picture becomes. I'm just so surprised that it influences all parts of the landscape even the parts that are not illuminated by the light at all..